# How is one saved?

Tags: soteriology, assurance-of-salvation

Therefore we conclude that **a man is justified by faith without the deeds of the law**. (Romans 3:28 KJV) According Paul is one justified by faith alone both in **Rom 3:28** and also mentioned in **Gal 2:16**.

The question is, are we saved merely by faith alone just as Paul writes in Rom 3:28 while in a chapter earlier (2:13) write that doers of the law are justified!?

Scriptures below emphasizes each a different aspect e.g endurance, obedience, by doings and also one verse seems to faith without works while another says with works.

**By faith**

> For by grace are ye saved **through faith**; and that not of yourselves:
> it is the gift of God: (Ephesians 2:8)

**By obedience**

> And being made perfect, he became the author of eternal salvation **unto
> all them that obey him** (Hebrews 5:9)

**By endurance**

> But **he that shall endure unto the end**, the same **shall be saved**.
> (Matthew 24:13)

**By doings**

> For not the hearers of the law are just before God, but **the doers of
> the law shall be justified**. (Romans 2:13)

**By faith alone**

> Knowing that a man is not justified by the works of the law, **but by
> the faith of Jesus Christ**, even we have believed in Jesus Christ, that
> we might be justified by the faith of Christ, **and not by the works of
> the law**: for by the works of the law shall no flesh be justified.
> (Galatians 2:16)

**Not by faith alone**

> You see that a person is considered righteous by what they do and **not
> by faith alone**. (James 2:24)

Comment: Hello and welcome! Because there are so many different Christian denominations and positions, most questions on this site need to be scoped to a particular denomination. Please have a read of [What types of questions can I ask on this site?](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3409/6071)

Comment: Welcome Daniel! Please choose  the perspective of a denomination or I fear your question will be closed as off topic. This question needs to be more focused. Pax.

Comment: Sometimes questions are directed at Catholics, or at Reformed Protestants, or they ask for an overview from Christian denominations.  Trouble with that last approach is the necessity to do a huge amount of research in order to cover different denominational beliefs.  Check out the options in Tags.  https://christianity.stackexchange.com/tags

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**How is one saved?**  To answer this question, we need to understand that salvation is a *journey* culminating in either heaven or hell.

You stated clearly in your comment that there is only one way to be saved, and you are right, as Jesus himself said: "I am the way and the truth and the life. No one comes to the Father except through me." ([John 14:6](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=john+14%3A6&version=NIV), NIV).

Now all verses you cited have their own place in this *journey* of salvation.  It's just different denominations arrange them differently.  For this answer, I try to be as general as possible, so this answer applies to all mainstream Trinitarian denominations.

1. **By Faith** (Eph 2:8).  This refers to the early stage of the journey when we are born again and receives new life ([John 3:3](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=john+3%3A3&version=NIV): Jesus replied, "Very truly I tell you, no one can see the kingdom of God unless they are born again.").  **This is God's gift that we don't earn**, since we need a mother to be born physically, and so we need God to be born spiritually.
2. **By Obedience** (Heb 5:9).  This refers to our proper response to God's gift of new life, by walking in the spirit ([Gal 5:16-18](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=gal+5%3A16-18&version=NIV)), obeying Jesus's "new commandment" of love ([John 15:12](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=John%2015%3A12&version=NIV)).
3. **By Endurance** (Matt 24:13).  This refers to the possibility that one may backslide or even apostatize.  That's why Paul warns us to faithfully "run with perseverance the race marked out for us, fixing our eyes on Jesus, the pioneer and perfecter of faith." ([Heb 12:1b-2a](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Hebrews+12%3A1-2&version=NIV)).
4. **By Doings** (Rom 2:13).  This refers to the standard that God judges us **BEFORE** the gift of faith.  This refers to Israelites who were given the laws at Sinai (so they "heard it"), but they didn't do it, so they broke the Mosaic covenant.  Please don't confuse this with the new covenant given by Jesus.  The "Doings" that Christians need to perform is in point #6 below.
5. **By faith alone** (Gal 2:16).  "justification" means right standing before God.  "justification" is only one part of the whole plan of salvation: to get us to heaven.  As mentioned above, we are justified only by faith, because only God can give us this new life.  Without this new life, we cannot enter heaven, the goal of this *journey* of salvation.
6. **Not by faith alone** (James 2:24).  This refers to our *response* to the gift of faith, not to *earn* salvation.  Remember, that the gift is in the beginning of the journey, but this point refers to the rest of the journey.  Response is a "proof" that our faith is genuine, that God *really* has given us this new life, not our attempt to "simulate" the effect of this new life.  Don't underestimate the ability for us to deceive ourselves!!  The bigger context is [James 2:14-17](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=James+2%3A14-17&version=NIV):

   > "What good is it, my brothers and sisters, if someone claims to have faith but has no deeds?  Can such faith save them? ... Faith by itself, if it is not accompanied by action, is dead."

   Again, this action is NOT to earn salvation, but as a response to the grace given by God.  Even our actions are only meritorious if is done under the power of grace so humans may not boast.